# How do I delete files from a timemachine backup

Tags: mac, time-machine, macos

So my mac was acting very slow and so I backed up all my files to an external hard drive using time machine and then proceeded to restart the entire mac. Now that I plug in my hard drive with my back up I dont really want to put it all back since my computer is running so much faster. My question is then how do i delete some files on that back up. Every time i press delete it says files can not be deleted from this back up time machine?

Comment: Deleting 1 file from a specific backup can corrupt the entire backup. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6):

You need to 'Enter Time Machine' by clicking on the menu bar icon that looks like a clock face. One of the options is to enter time machine. This transforms your screen temporarily into a time machine window. From there you can select and delete time machine files.

Comment: `From there you can select and delete time machine files.`  Sorry, I must be missing something... I can select the file(s), but I don't see any way to delete it/them.  MacOS 10.14, and 1.5 years after your answer, so maybe this is no longer possible?

Comment: is there an icon that looks like a gear on each backup pane. If you click on this icone it should show you an option to delete.

Comment: Many thanks for the speedy reply.  Must have changed with an OS update... i only see open, restore, get info, quick look, and copy (same as the right click options).  No delete :-(

Comment: I think I discovered where the issue is... I have my USB hard drive Time Machine, and then there is the "local" TM which (I think?) is buffering local backups until the next time I connect the USB TM.  I was entering TM (clock icon) without the USB drive plugged in.  I wanted to delete a screencast that I forgot to stop (11.1GB file on Desktop), no reason to fill up the USB drive.  But that doesn't work.  Once I plugged in the USB TM, I could select "Delete".  Hope that makes sense?  Many thanks again for replying!

Comment: great. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 6):

A straight deletion will only get rid of the file selected in the individual backup you're addressing. However, when in Time Machine, right-clicking on a file will show an option to delete all instances of the selected file in the current and other Time Machine backups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and upvoted... but... ` right-clicking on a file will show an option to delete all instances of the selected file in the current and other Time Machine backups`:  I must be missing something... I can select the file(s), but I don't see any way to delete it/them.  MacOS 10.14, and 1.5 years after your answer, so maybe this is no longer possible?

Comment: @Dan I just tried it (macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, updated), and right-clicking offers me a "delete" selection. You must be viewing the file from within Time Machine, and not in the Finder.

Comment: thanks very much for replying.  I think I discovered where the issue is... so I have my hard drive (USB) TIme Machine, and then the "local" TM which (I think?) is buffering local backups until the next time I connect the USB TM.  I was entering TM (clock icon) without the USB drive plugged in.  I wanted to delete a screencast that I forgot to stop (11.1GB file on Desktop), no reason to fill up the USB drive.  But that doesn't work.  Once I plugged in the USB TM, I could select "Delete".  Hope that makes sense?  Many thanks again for replying.

Comment: For others who found their way here, I don't think this is possible on APFS external drives.

Comment: @RushilSrivastava that is correct and it is due to APFS technology, not Time Machine per se. *Any* APFS snapshot will be ready-only. [source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskuf82354dc/mac).

Answer (score 1):

*Right click*, then *delete all instances* used to work in earlier macOS versions but sadly it no longer does in macOS 14 Sonoma. Now, the only right click options you have are *restore, copy, and info*. Delete is gone.

[image]

I hate when developers just silently break a useful function. Then you update your OS hoping for a better OS and suddenly it's worse.

The easiest thing to do is probably to create another backup and delete the entire old one via Terminal and [tmutil](https://www.lifewire.com/delete-time-machine-backups-5219464).