# Delete certain file from TimeMachine using tmutil

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, macos

I want to delete a certain file from TimeMachine. Using "Delete all backups of..." from the gear/context menu doesn't do anything. No warning/error message appears.

What I've [found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310575/how-do-i-delete-files-from-a-timemachine-backup) is that messing with TimeMachine directly from BASH is risky; a better way is to use `tmutil`.

**Question**: is `tmutil` capable of deleting individual files, i.e. doing a "Delete all backups of...", but from the command line?

Context: this file I'm so keen to delete is an .exe which has been recently marked as containing a trojan by Bitdefender. I want to keep my TimeMachine backup malware free. The .exe file is unimportant because it was compiled from C#. Probably the virtual machine I used to compile it was infected.